# String compression for repeated chars

Tags: c#, string, compression

I have the two following strings.

```
uncompressed "(A(2),I(10),A,A,A,A(3),R,R,R,R,A,A)"
compressed "(A(2),I(10),3A,A(3),4R,2A)"
```

Ignoring any entries in the format A(n) or I(n) you can see that when we find any consecutive repeated char it is replaced with a single entry at that position and a count.

I know there must be an elegant way to do this but I keep coming up with ugly looking nested loops.

The data in the strings comes from the ISO8211 file format and identify the format to apply to data in the sub fields.

I am sure this could be done with a single line of linq but I am out of ideas (tonight.)

Comment: Please add the relevant language tags to your question.

Comment: I take it this is C# (VB.NET?) since you said LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique is called [Run Length Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Here's an example using Python:

```
from itertools import groupby
uncompressed = "(A(2),I(10),A,A,A,A(3),R,R,R,R,A,A)"
counted = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(uncompressed.split(','))]
compressed = ','.join(k if cnt==1 else str(cnt)+k for k, cnt in counted)
```

Comment: Excellent, for all my googling I could not seem to frame the question correctly to receive even a hint of the trail. Run length encoding is not mentioned in the ISO8211 spec, genius. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not exactly a single line. This will do it:

```
string str = "(A(2),I(10),A,A,A,A(3),R,R,R,R,A,A)";

string prev = null;
int cnt = 0;
string result =
  "(" + String.Join(",",
  (str.TrimStart('(').TrimEnd(')') + ",").Split(',').Select(x => {
    if (x == prev) {
      cnt++;
      return null;
    } else {
      string temp = cnt > 1 ? cnt.ToString() + prev : prev;
      prev = x;
      cnt = 1;
      return temp;
    }
  }).Where(x => x != null)
) + ")";
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is very similar to my current solution. I have marked the answer from Raymond Hettinger as the answer as it names the encoding method. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to do that, using LINQ's `GroupBy`:

```
static string RLE(string s) {
    s = s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2);

    char? l = null;
    int i = 0;

    return "(" + string.Join(",", s.Split(',').GroupBy(c => {
        if(c.Length != 1) {
            i++;
            return i++;
        }

        if(c[0] == l) {
            return i;
        }

        l = c[0];
        return ++i;
    }).Select(x => (x.Count() > 1 ? x.Count().ToString() : string.Empty) + x.First())) + ")";
}
```